# Not Responding is shown in title bar

Tags: c#

I am calling a server api and waiting for response. I can continue only after getting response from server. But some times the server response are received, only after a  time delay, and my title bar show Not responding message. How can i solve this.

My code block is

```
    private string SubmitDocument(XmlDocument xmlinput, string URL)
    {
        try
        {
            // get the data from the xml document into a byte stream
            Byte[] byteinput = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlinput.OuterXml);

            // instantiate a web client
            System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
            myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml");

            byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadData(URL, byteinput);


            string responseString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);


            return responseString;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {                
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Rather than block the UI, do this work on a background thread (perhaps `BackgroundWorker`, perhaps `ThreadPool`). Since it sounds like you want to emulate synchronous, simply **disable** the UI controls - don't hang the form. Then update the UI when you *do* get a response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest implement async call back. This will make your app responsive. You could implement async call back easily through webrequest class.

Answer (score -1):

Windows shows a non responding message in the application tittle when the window proc loop (that is, your main application thread) does not process messages.

This happens when your main application thread is busy in some sort of wait or loop (just as you describe and cannot handle windows messages).

You have some options, since the application can't continue until it gets the response from the server you have to options:

1. Wait for the server on a second thread and let your application "stopped" until the response is received (and by stopped I mean handling user interface but unable to do anything else, for example with a progress bar and a semaphore).
2. Use Application.DoEvents() from time to time. For this to work you need to be able to wait for the server only for a period of time:

---

```
while (!initialized)
{
  Application.DoEvents();
  initialized = Server.WaitInitialize(1000);
}
```